# How can i parse this JSON complicated deep dictionary data using swift 3

Tags: json, parsing, dictionary, swift3, nested

How can I parse this JSON data using swift3. I am trying to convert this into [String: Any] dictionary.

I am using JSONSerialization to parse this data but not able to correctly parse. This data have nested dictionaries how can I parse this?
Can anyone help me to sort this out?

```
{
    "info": {
        "imdb_id": "",
        "movie_image": "http://abc/images/2072233.jpg",
        "genre": "Action / Crime / Thriller",
        "plot": "Il est prêt à tout pour sauver son fils et il n’a qu’une nuit devant lui.",
        "cast": "JMatthew Cornwell / Marisol Correa / Stephen Dean / Rayshaun Deese / Deborah Wilkins / Derrick Worsley",
        "rating": "5.6",
        "director": "Baran bo Odar",
        "releasedate": "9 août 2017",
        "duration_secs": 5691,
        "duration": "01:34:51",
        "video": {
            "index": 0,
            "time_base": "1/16000",
            "start_pts": 672,
            "start_time": "0.042000",
            "duration_ts": 91070976,
            "duration": "5691.936000",
            "bit_rate": "4537543",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "136469",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        },
        "audio": {
            "index": 2,
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "dmix_mode": "-1",
            "ltrt_cmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "ltrt_surmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "loro_cmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "loro_surmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "nb_frames": "177873",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "SoundHandler"
            },
            "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "Audio Service Type"
                }
            ]
        },
        "bitrate": 5058
    }
}

//How can i parse this JSON data using swift3
//I am using JSONSerialization to parse this data but not able to correctly parse. This data have nested dictionaries how can i parse this?
```

Comment: Questions about parsing JSON are one of the most frequently asked questions here on SO. Except the value for key `side_data_list` all child objects are dictionaries. Get the values with key subscription. For example you get the `info` dictionary with `json["info"] as! [String:Any]` and so on.

Comment: @vadian This data not even converting in JSON using JSON serialization, it always return nil when try to convert NSData to JSON

Comment: The root object is also a dictionary `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data) as! [String:Any]`

Comment: Using this i get this error: `Could not cast value of type '__NSArray0' (0x104fffaa0) to 'NSDictionary'` @vadian

Comment: That means the JSON in your question is wrong respectively not the JSON you are going to parse.

Comment: vadian has provided you with the required information to solve your task. If that is not sufficient, please post your attempt at JSONSerialization so we can give you hints on where you could fix it. You will have more luck to get a solution that way rather than expecting someone here to figure out the entire code for you :)

Comment: @LouisLeung `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]` returning me nil

Comment: @KamaljeetSingh hey there, we will need to see more than one line at a time. My suggestion is post at least the entire function you are calling to retrieve the JSON (if it is from a remote source: IMDB?).  Include this as an edit to your original question.

Comment: @LouisLeung `super.httpRequest(params: requestDict) { (responseData) in
            //here got NSData
            guard let data = responseData else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                print("json response: ", json!)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }` 
Thank you for your response :)

Comment: @LouisLeung Here is what super.httpRequest method doing `let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                finished(responseData)
                return
            }
            responseData = data
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                // check for http errors
            }
            finished(responseData)
        }
        task.resume()`

Comment: I am so sorry @LouisLeung. i got the error.  that was my fault. i was hitting the wrong request. sorry and thank you for your quick response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to dicipher from what you posted in the comments, but here goes for parsing the imdb_id:

```
super.httpRequest(params: requestDict) { (responseData) in 
    guard let data = responseData else { return } 
    do { 
         let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] 

           if let info = json["info"] as? [String: Any] {
                let id = info["imdb_id"] as? String 
                print("The imdb_id is \(id)")
           }
       } catch let error as NSError { 
              print(error) 
    } 
}
```

What do you see printed out?